# Manhattan Ferry/Water taxi to Brooklyn Bridge park

Tags: transportation, new-york-city

I will be staying in NYC in a hotel in the Times Square area.

One day I would like to go to the Brooklyn Bridge park area.

Is there are way I can do so by one boat leaving the Midtown / West 39th street pier?

Or much less preferrably E. 34th st. Midtown pier?

Or if I would have to use two boats, does the private NYC water taxi have the concept of a transfer, such that I would pay for one ride?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ferries that serve the Fulton landing at the north end of Brooklyn Bridge Park: the East River Ferry, which doesn't serve the west side of Manhattan, and New York Water Taxi, which does.

http://www.eastriverferry.com/
https://www.nywatertaxi.com/

There's a ferry landing at the south end of the park, but as far as I know it's used only for seasonal service to Governor's Island.

The water taxi seems to require you to buy an all-day pass for $31, and it takes about 50 minutes to get from West 39th street to Brooklyn Bridge Park.

From Times Square, I would probably take the A train to High Street, but if I were determined to take the ferry, I would take the M34 bus and get the East River Ferry at East 34th St.  The fare is much lower ($4 or $6 each way, the higher price on weekends, and an all-day pass $12 or $18); the duration is about 25 minutes, and the service is more frequent.